# Mac OSX Shell script parse ISO 8601 date and add one second?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, date-parsing

I am trying to figure out how to parse a file with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)-formatted time stamps, add one second and then output them to a file.

All the examples I have found don't really tell me how to do it with ISO 8601 date/time strings.

Example:
read a csv of times like: "2017-02-15T18:47:59"  (some are correct, others are not)

and spit out in a new file "2017-02-15T18:48:00"

mainly just trying to correct a bunch of dates that have 59 seconds at the end to round up to the 1 second mark.

This is my current progress:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    # startd=$(date -j -f '%Y%m%d' "$line" +'%Y%m%d'); 
    # echo "$startd";
    startd=$(date -j -u -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" $line) 
    #startd=$(date -j -f '%Y%m%d' "$line" +'%Y%m%d'); 
    echo "$startd";

done < "$1"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

[jm666's helpful `perl` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42285755/45375) will be much faster than your shell loop-based approach.

That said, if you want to make your `bash` code work on macOS, with its *BSD* `date` implementation, here's a solution:

```
# Define the input date format, which is also used for output.
fmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'

# Note: -j in all date calls below is needed to suppress setting the 
#       system date.
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

    # Parse the line at hand using input format specifier (-f) $fmt, 
    # and output-format specifier (+) '%s', which outputs a Unix epoch
    # timestamp (in seconds).
    ts=$(date -j -f "$fmt" "$line" +%s)

    # See if the seconds-component (%S) is 59...
    if [[ $(date -j -f %s "$ts" +%S) == '59' ]]; then
      # ... and, if so, add 1 second (-v +1S).
      line=$(date -j -f %s -v +1S "$ts" +"$fmt")
    fi

    # Output the possibly adjusted timestamp.
    echo "$line"

done < "$1"
```

Note that input dates such as `2017-02-15T18:47:59` are interpreted as *local* time, because they contain no time-zone information.

Answer (score 1):

This could do the job

```
perl -MTime::Piece -nlE '$f=q{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S};$t=Time::Piece->strptime($_,$f)+1;say $t->strftime($f)' < dates.txt
```

if the `dates.txt` contains

```
2017-02-15T18:47:59
2016-02-29T23:59:59
2017-02-28T23:59:59
2015-12-31T23:59:59
2010-10-10T10:10:10
```

the above produces

```
2017-02-15T18:48:00
2016-03-01T00:00:00
2017-03-01T00:00:00
2016-01-01T00:00:00
2010-10-10T10:10:11
```